# ng-table pagination click event

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using `ng-table` for displaying a grid in angularjs. I want to use the ng-click event of the default pagination of ng-table table.I have tried using the method `$scope.params.count()` and `$scope.params()` which is on the ng-click of the pagination but it is not working.Is there any method that can be used to customize the click event of default pagination of ng-table

Comment: Show us the code of what you've tried so far

Comment: basic ng-table but just want to control the ng-click event of the pagination of ng-table.

Comment: Did you managed to find solution for this issue?